# How to list all users that have terminal sessions, including screen sessions?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I would like to have a list of all users that are active on my Linux system, including those who have running but detached screen sessions. The `who` command only shows me currently logged in users, but not users with detached screen sessions and the like.

I was contemplating parsing the output of `ps` but that would also make a user show if if he has a cron job running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$ ps axno user,tty | awk '$1 >= 1000 && $1 < 65530 && $2 != "?"' | sort -u
```

This should tell you all UIDs with processes with a session terminal (like a window in screen).  I use the UID to be weed out the 'system' users (like apache) and nobody (high UID), and ignore daemons.

Answer (score 2):

You can try who, and the output of ps with a grep:

```
~$ ps aux | grep screen
```

And filter on user:

```
~$  ps aux | grep screen | grep $USER
```

(replace $user with the username).